# ASP.Net core 2.1 applicationsettings.json entityframework setting

Tags: configuration, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.0

I just added a new ASP.Net core 2.1 project to our solution. This is will be our API app. It is using our existing libraries which is in .Net 4.6.1. One of the libraries deals with data access using EF and I get the following error:

'Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.'

Our web app works fine which is in .Net 4.6.1 and uses the web.config file.
The new API app uses the appsetting.json. I dont know how to config the EF configs in that file.
Below are relevant sections of the web.config. Can anybody please tell me how I can config this in .Net Core2.1

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```